# Related to Unit Sphere of Equivalence Norms

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

In $R^{2}$, given $||(x, y)|| = |x + y| + 2|y - x|$

The problem asks me c) to sketch the unit sphere for this: $B_{1}(0) =$ {(x, y) $∈ R^{2}$ | $||(x, y)|| < 1$}

The radius here is 1, and the origin here is $0$. But what is the meaning of index 1 of $B_{1}$ here? How do we plot unit sphere for equivalence norms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is just the radius of the ball, is in:
\begin{align}
B_r(0) &= \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ ||(x,y)|| \le r\}
\end{align}
(depending on context, the ball might be defined with either '$\le$' ('closed ball') or '$<$' ('open ball')).

The 'sphere' is just the set of points exactly distance $1$ from the origin. I.e. you need to find all solutions of

\begin{align}
|x + y| + 2|y - x| = 1
\end{align}

Depending on your experience you might or might not immediately see the shape of the solution-set, but here are some ways you might to want to think about it:

- Try to get a couple of example points and draw them on a piece of paper. Good points to start are probably those where one of the two terms becomes zero. For example $x=y=0.5$ works, because $|0.5 + 0.5| + 2|0.5 - 0.5| = 1$. next, try to change the values a little bit. for example set $x=0.4$ and figure out what $y$ is then.
- Alternatively: split the problem into four cases, depending on on weather $x+y$ is positive or negative and depending on weather $x-y$ is positive or negative. In all four cases, you can get rid of the $|\cdot|$ in the formula, leaving you with a four simple linear equations.
- Or more abstractly: Consider a coordinate transformation $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$ (this is a 45 degree rotation plus a stretch by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$). The formula than becomes
  \begin{align}
  |u| + 2|v| = 1
  \end{align}
  Figure out the shape in the u-v-plane and than transform back.

In any case, note that the shape you are looking for will be a kind of rectangle, not a circle. But it is still called a 'sphere' in mathematics. Dont let that confuse you ;)